# Could someone explain what this piece of code means in Oracle PL/ SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
return split_tbl as
splitted split_tbl := split_tbl();
i pls_integer := 0;
list_ varchar2(32767) := list;
```

Seen this in a lot of code blocks not able to understand how it works though, could someone explain what it means and how it works?

Comment: Which line you don't understand?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit    this one splitted split_tbl := split_tbl();

Answer (score 1):

Looks like piece of a function that

- returns custom datatype - `split_tbl` (someone created it with `CREATE TYPE split_tbl ...`)
- `splitted` is a locally declared variable. Its datatype is `split_tbl` (I believe that function returns `splitted`) and is *initialized* (that's what `:= split_tbl()` does)
- `i` is another local variable, its datatype is `pls_integer` and is initialized to `0` (so that, if you later use it as e.g. `i := i + 1` you don't add `1` to `NULL` which would also be `NULL`).
- `list_` is a `varchar2` datatype variable, its size is maximum allowed (32767 characters or bytes), and is initialized to `list` which is *something*, but we can't tell what

Comment: why the parenthesis after split_tbl only and not also after := list ? @Littlefoot

Comment: Because SPLIT_TBL is a collection. LIST is a string (varchar2 datatype).

Comment: Thanks ! Is there any reference / documentation where i can find more information ? @Littlefoot

Comment: Sure; any Oracle database version's SQL Reference book and - for collections - PL/SQL Reference.

Comment: If the answer has helped you then please accept it. Accepting helpful answers helps future questioners facing the same or similar issues. Please do not a successfully answered question as open. If it did not successfully answer tour question then what is your remaining issue.